# Is there a way to limit the use of an ssh tunnel to a single user?

Tags: linux, networking, security, ssh, permissions

I've created a tunnel between a shared machine and my machine which is behind a firewall, with the goal of accessing my machine from outside. I don't one all the users of the shared machine to be able to access my machine, though. So is there a way to set "ownership" on an ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The best you can do is use the `owner` module in iptables to drop packets not generated by a process owned by you.

Answer (score 1):

This may not help you specifically, but if you wanted to solve this problem in a general fashion you could use SELinux to control access. Of course you would need to coordinate with the admin of the shared box for that.